# Spring boot repository query to return a ordered result

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student, String>  {
    
    Page<Student> findByIdInAndNameLike(List<String> ids, String name, Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

**In Service layer :**

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
   
studentRepository.findByIdInAndNameLike(idList, name, pageable );
```

Here this `idList` is an ordered list. And I need to get the search results according to the order of that `idList`.

eg : `List<String> idList= Arrays.asList("123", "111", "213");`

So here the Student with id 123 should come first. And student with id 213 should come last.

Comment: SQL queries are not particularly good at doing this especially with Pageables. You might be able to get away with it using a List but because you can't insert into a Page this is nearly impossible. In my opinion the best way to do this would be to convert the Page to a List and then order them the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) u have to provide the 3rd parameter to PageRequest which exactly does the sorting for you

```
Pageable sortedByName = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("id"));
```